# DialogBox code Master Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an asp.net application and in Right-Top corner I want to show "Contact Us" link. On click of this link button, a popup should open and rest area should be greyed out.

Now, to show Contact US in all pages of application, it must be added to master page. Below is the masterpage code which I am trying to modify but somehow the dialog box doesn't open. Ofcourse due to placing of div. Can someone guide me please ?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="mstMainPage.master.cs"
    Inherits="TestProj.Master.mstMainPage" %>

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style>
         .ui-widget-header,.ui-state-default, ui-button{
            background:#b9cd6d;
            border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
         }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
            $("#btnContactUs").click(function() {

               ($("#dialog-5").dialog("isOpen") == false) ? $("#dialog-5").dialog("open") : $("#dialog-5").dialog("close") ;
            });
            $("#dialog-5").dialog({autoOpen: false});
         });

        function CloseWindow() {
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top: -5px; margin-left: -5px; margin-right: 0px; border-color: #79ACCA; border-width">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <!-- Main Panel -->
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="100%" Style="margin-left: 0px">
            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tab1" Width="100%">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Height="28px" Width="100%" BackColor="#79ACCA" HorizontalAlign="Right">
                         <asp:Button ID="btnContactUs" runat="server" Text="Contact Us" >
                        </asp:Button>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>           
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="ContentMargin">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMSTMainPage" runat="server">
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </asp:Panel>
         <div id="dialog-5" title="Dialog Title!">
            Click on the Toggle button to open and close this dialog box.
         </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception ??

Comment: No. When I click on Contact Us, it just reloads the page.

Comment: Put alert msg on button click and check your button click is working or not.

Comment: You can stop submitting form and avoid postback by setting `UseSubmitBehavior = false` on button else I have added an answer you can try that one.

Answer (score 1):

If page reloading is causing this issue then try this way.

**Aspx Markup:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnContactUs" runat="server" Text="Contact Us" CssClass="LogOff" OnClientClick="OpenDialog(this);return false;"></asp:Button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function OpenDialog(jObj) {
    ($("#dialog-5").dialog("isOpen") == false) ? $("#dialog-5").dialog("open"): $("#dialog-5").dialog("close");
}
```

Comment: Have a cross check in developer console under inspect element div with id `dialog-5` available in dom?

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors....the solution with Master and Content Pages is to add a re-positioning line of code in the `open` or `create` dialog initialization.

```
function (evt) {    // @open
    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
}
```

This will move the dialog box back inside the Form element